# How to add certain values to all y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I am having a huge issue with plotting contour plots for these listed data as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLeDK.jpg).

Since this data requires some corrections, I have to manage to add 50 to all y-axis values, but I do not know how to do.

Here is the code that I am currently using.

Imports:

```py
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd
    import glob
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    from matplotlib import ticker
```

Part 1: single file processing + setting inputs

```
    path = r'C:\Users\keonw\Desktop\PPT\MACl 실험 자료\Insitu PL and transmission raw data\Insitu PL\Ambient data\s3_40'
    files = glob.glob(path  + "\*.txt")


    #Wavelength region to be plotted
    y_start = 300  # min value 200
    y_end   = 900   # max value 990

    #number of spectra to evaluate (meaning time frame plotted)
    shortening = True
    t_end = 1800
    t_start = 900

    #time integer between measurements in [s]
    time_integer = 0.1


    # Logarithmic Plot
    LogPlots = True

    #Color map
    colour = plt.cm.jet

    #Text size for graphics:
    text_size = 25


    # conversion of the Wavelength inputs into correpsonding line numbers
    l_start = int(- 1007.1 + 3*y_start)
    l_end = int(- 1007.1 + 3*y_end)

    # Setting the name for saving the file
    name = path[2:]     # the command cuts out the first 2 items from the name
    name_d = '.\Fig_' + name        #this is the name for the saved image





    # data reading and initial preparation

    #reading all files
    df_all = np.concatenate([pd.read_csv(f,sep="\t",header=14) for f in files],axis=1)


    #seperating wavelength values
    df_y=df_all[:,0]

    #deleting every other column (all wavelength values) leaving only intsities
    df=np.delete(df_all, list(range(0, df_all.shape[1], 2)), axis=1)  
      
    #removing negative points from data (important for log plot, also helps with scaling)
    df = np.where(df <= 0, 0, df)
```

Part 2: shaping the data frame

```
    # 1. row-wise (selecting the wavelengths to be plotted)

    #shortening the wavelength region to interesting region
    #region defined by l_start and l_end which are defined in the beginnig
    df=np.delete(df, list(range(l_end, df_all.shape[0], 1)), axis=0)
    df=np.delete(df, list(range(0, l_start, 1)), axis=0)


    #same shortening for the Y-axis array
    df_y=np.delete(df_y, list(range(l_end, df_y.shape[0], 1)), axis=0)
    df_y=np.delete(df_y, list(range(0, l_start, 1)), axis=0)


    # 2. column-wise (selecting the time frame)

    #shortening the time region - will call t_end as number of lines
    if shortening is True:
        df=np.delete(df, list(range(t_end, df.shape[1], 1)), axis=1)  
        df=np.delete(df, list(range(0, t_start, 1)), axis=1)  
    else:
        t_start = 0

    # defining an x-axis

    # defining X-axis and time frame from random point without reading any time value from the file
    df_x1= list(range(df.shape[1])) #gives array with index values
    df_x= [t_start* time_integer + i * time_integer for i in df_x1] #rescaling with real distance between measurements
```

Part 3: plotting commands

```
    # command for plotting either contour or contourf
    #
    # Linear PLot
    #

    fig = plt.contourf(df_x, df_y, df ,200,cmap=colour)


    # Make a color bar for the ContourSet 

    cbar = plt.colorbar(fig)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel('PL intensity (a.u.)',fontname="Arial", fontsize= text_size)  
    cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([])  

    #adding labels 
    plt.xlabel('Time elapsed (s)',fontname="Arial", fontsize= text_size)  
    '''
    plt.xticks([0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20])
    '''

    plt.xticks([90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180], fontsize= 14)

    plt.ylabel('Wavelength (nm)',fontname= "Arial", fontsize= text_size)  
    plt.yticks([450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950,1000,1050], fontsize= 14)
    #plt.title(str(name) + ' - Linear Plot',fontsize= text_size)  

    #saving the figure:
    plt.savefig(str(name_d)+'-LinPlot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
    # at the end you want to close the current plot with:
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: Its not clear what your question is.  Also, please consider providing  _minimal_ example, not all your code.